# In rails, How to determine if a record was destroyed by a dependent: :destroy callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I've got a record in my Rails app with an `after_destroy` hook that needs to be aware of why the record gets destroyed. More specifically, if the record is being destroyed in a cascade because its parent says `dependent: :destroy`, it needs to do things differently than if the record was individually destroyed.

What I tried to do is to see if its parent was `destroyed?`, only to figure out that `dependent: :destroy` callbacks are done before the parent is destroyed. Which makes sense because it should be able to fail. (i.e. restrict).

So, how do I do this?

Comment: @eabraham As I wrote in my question: What I tried to do is to see if its parent was `destroyed?`, only to figure out that `dependent: :destroy` callbacks are done before the parent is destroyed. In other words: that is useless, the paren't can't be destroyed as the dependent callback is issued before the parent gets destroyed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution #1**

If your model is simple enough and you don't need to invoke any callbacks in the child relation, you can just use `dependent: delete_all` in the parent.

**Solution #2**

For more complex scenarios you can use `destroyed_by_association`, which returns a `ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection` object when it's part of cascade, or nil otherwise:

```
after_destroy :your_callback

def your_callback
  if destroyed_by_association
    # this is part of a cascade
  else
    # isolated deletion
  end
end
```

I just tried this in Rails 4.2 and it works.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12828#issuecomment-28142658

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using the `before_destroy` callback in the parent object to mark all child objects as destroyed through parent destroy. Like this:

```
class YourClass
  before_destroy :mark_children

  ...
  ...

  def mark_children
    [:association1, :association2].each do |association|   # Array should include association names that hate :dependent => :destroy option
      self.send(association).each do |child|
        # mark child object as deleted by parent
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use ActiveRecord reflections to determine automatically which associations are marked as `:dependent => :destroy`. Doing this is helpful when you need this function in many classes.