# Prevent object destruction except by parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4: I have a parent object and a child object. I have a `before_destroy` callback for the child object that may prevent its destruction based on a flag. However, I also need its parent to be able to destroy it via a `dependent: :destroy` relationship.

How can I check the source of its destruction in my validation?

I found `marked_for_destruction?` and a host of related questions here, but none seem concerned with the `before_destroy` callback, which runs before the object (or even its parent) are marked for destruction. I've been prying through what's accessible in the callback for a while now and can't seem to find anything.

I could obviously go with `dependent: :delete` instead, although that seems like it misses the point. I'm sure I could come up with something else like doing a before_destroy on the parent, and then calling a monkey-patched `destroy` method with some arguments or some such thing, but it also seems to miss the point.

Any suggestions? Is there some property on the parent that I'm missing, or a way to trace the `destroy` call's source or something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find hints here: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/rails-prevent-the-destruction-of-child-object-when-parent-requires-its-presence/

Comment: Looks like this prior question takes the `before_destroy` approach you mention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578812/in-rails-how-to-determine-if-a-record-was-destroyed-by-a-dependent-destroy-ca

Comment: One more quick thing: according to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), `:dependent` "is implemented using Rails' callback system" so placement of other filters around it may cause odd behavior.

Comment: Both super helpful, thank you both very much.